# How I can build listview scroll inside container?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How I can make listview horizontal scroll like the image

Another explanation I want to build such a scroll list inside the black container
**Screenshot**

![enter image description here][1]

**Code**

```
    body: Center (
       child: Container(
        height: 400.0,
        width: 300.0,        
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 90.0),
          child: ListView(
            // This next line does the trick.
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),    
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

do you know about column widget ? if no then try it and tell me if this what you want or not

Comment: ok after you changed your post now its more clear i would say you need a column widget add the first child of column widget a card widget then add listview as a child to card

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Center` widget by `Align` and set the `alignment` according what you need:

```
            body: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, // or Alignment.topCenter
                      child: Container(
                        height: 200.0,
                        width: 300.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Container(
                            child: ListView(     
                            ...
```

Comment: bro I mean ListView Alignment inside the white container

Comment: Yep, don't forget to remove the margin from your container

Comment: bro you move the white box not the listview
i need move position of the listview to top or inside white box

Comment: Could you update your question with my code and see how it works? Add a screenshot

Comment: Update your question using my code to check if it is correct

Comment: bro i found image explain what i need so i need same

Comment: Ok, did you use the code I put in my answer? If it yes, update your code in the question, and show us the result using a screenshot

Comment: it just move container bro

Comment: Please, update the code and add a screenshot to see the result

Comment: bro take look to the image above i need same

Comment: again, check my answer, and update your code using my answer.